# Dynamic updating problem

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, variable-definitions, variable

Consider the code

```
Manipulate[sli, Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Consider option 3", Control[{{use, True, ""}, {True, False}}]},
    {"Options", 
     Control[{{sli, 1, ""}, {1 -> "Option 1", 2 -> "Option 2", 
        If[use, 3 -> "Option 3", Nothing]}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]}},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

Where Option 3 is only available if the first checkbox is true. Now, imagine I've selected option 3 and then uncheck the checkbox. I get

[image]

Option 3 remains selected, but no longer available on the popup menu. Is it possible to automatically pick any of the other options and maintain editability? That is, I could fix `sli = 1` whenever the box is unchecked, but that forced me to stay in Option 1, as shown here

```
Manipulate[If[! use, sli = 1]; sli, Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Consider option 3", Control[{{use, True, ""}, {True, False}}]},
    {"Options", 
     Control[{{sli, 1, ""}, {1 -> "Option 1", 2 -> "Option 2", 
        If[use, 3 -> "Option 3", Nothing]}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]}},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic to `If[(! use) && prevUse, sli = 1]; prevUse = use;`.

This will make sure you reset `sli` only on `True -> False` transition of `use`.

```
Manipulate[
 If[(! use) && prevUse, sli = 1]; prevUse = use;
 sli,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Consider option 3", Control[{{use, True, ""}, {True, False}}]},
    {"Options", Control[{{sli, 1, ""}, {
        1 -> "Option 1",
        2 -> "Option 2",
        If[use, 3 -> "Option 3", Nothing]
        }, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]]
```

Comment: But how do you make `sli` be either 1 or 2 (it can be randomly chosen) after you uncheck `use` while `sli` is set to 3? Basically I want to automatically update the value of `sli` to one of the two possible values (1 or 2) exclusively in the case where `sli = 3` and I uncheck `use`.

Comment: Oh, okay, then the most straightforward way is to use `If[(! use) && prevUse, sli = 1]; prevUse = use;`. Will update the answer.